How to see who deleted the ADO pipeline builds from the pipelines?
I'm an project administrator in the Azure DevOps for 2 of the projects.
But I'm able to see the option "View Deleted Pipelines" for one project:

And for 2nd project also, I'm the project administrator but cannot see the option of "View Deleted Pipelines"

What could be the reason - Is there any setting to be enabled in Project Settings or Organization settings?
(or)
Am I missing any project specific permission?

Hi @Jashua Criss, as mentioned by Marcel, you can delete one pipeline, refresh the browser and check if you can see the View deleted pipelines option. Then you can restore it.

The "View deleted pipelines" option only appears if you or someone already deleted a pipeline on the project. Otherwise, you won't have that option.
